# Is there a way to parse xml in docusign?

Tags: xml-parsing, docusignapi

Is there a way to parse xml in docusign? And if so, how does this work? I do not find any user guide or something like this.

Thank you for your support

Comment: what XML? how does it relate to DocuSign? do you mean using the SOAP API?

Comment: Hello,
please excuse the confusion. I'll start over. 
Situation:
I have an AD from which I get the value X and Y. I want to parse this to the value XY in docusign to match the value XY with the field permissionprofileid. 

To my question, is this possible and if so how?
Or is it only possible via the REST API and if so how?

I would appreciate your feedback.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the REST API. the SOAP API is very old and not actively being worked on.
To retrieve values from a DocuSign "form" (we call it an envelope) you can use the following [code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/get-envelope-tab-values):

Here is a C# snippet, you get back at the end JSON with all the form data.

```
    // Step 1: Obtain your OAuth token
    var accessToken = RequestItemsService.User.AccessToken; // Represents your {ACCESS_TOKEN}
    var accountId = RequestItemsService.Session.AccountId; // Represents your {ACCOUNT_ID}
    var envelopeId = RequestItemsService.EnvelopeId;

    // Step 2: Construct your API headers
    var config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
    config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

    // Step 3: Call the eSignature REST API
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
    EnvelopeFormData results = envelopesApi.GetFormData(accountId, envelopeId);
```